# Grouping by column and finding preceeding value of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, lag

I have a very long sales data, below an exemplary excerpt:

```
|    Date    | CountryA | CountryB | PriceA | PriceB |  |
+------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--+
| 05/09/2019 | US       | Japan    |     20 |     55 |  |
| 28/09/2019 | Japan    | Germany  |     30 |     28 |  |
| 16/10/2019 | Canada   | US       |     25 |     78 |  |
| 28/10/2019 | Germany  | Japan    |     60 |     17 |  |
+------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--+
```

I would like to group on column "CountryB" and then generate a new column which displays the preceding value of PriceA of that respective country, i.e. when that specific country was present in column "CountryA" the last time based on date order. In this exemplary table, I want to get the following results:

```
|    Date    | CountryA | CountryB | PriceA | PriceB | PriceA_lag1 |  |
+------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+--+
| 05/09/2019 | US       | Japan    |     20 |     55 |             |  |
| 28/09/2019 | Japan    | Germany  |     30 |     28 |             |  |
| 16/10/2019 | Canada   | US       |     25 |     78 |          20 |  |
| 28/10/2019 | Germany  | Japan    |     60 |     17 |          30 |  |
+------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+--+
```

I have tried the following with dplyr:

```
data=data%>%group_by(CountryB)%>%mutate_at(list(lag1=~dplyr::lag(.,1,order_by=Date)),.vars=vars(PriceA))
```

However this does not give me the preceding value when the respective country is in column "CountryA", but rather when the respective country is in "CountryB".

Can someone please help me out on this one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possibly some of the ugliest code I've written, but...

```
# install.packages('dplyr', 'magrittr')
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

d <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("05/09/2019", "28/09/2019", "16/10/2019", "28/10/2019"),
          CountryA = c("US", "Japan", "Canada", "Germany"),
          CountryB = c("Japan", "Germany", "US", "Japan"),
            PriceA = c(20L, 30L, 25L, 60L),
            PriceB = c(55L, 28L, 78L, 17L)
) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y'))

priceA_lag <- c()
for(row in 1:nrow(d)){
  
  country <- slice(d, row) %$% CountryB
  date <- slice(d, row) %$% Date
  
  thePrice <- d %>% 
    filter(CountryA == country,
           date > Date) %>%
    filter(Date == max(Date)) %$%
    PriceA
  
  thePrice <- ifelse(length(thePrice) > 0, thePrice, NA)
  
  priceA_lag <- priceA_lag %>%
    append(thePrice)
  
}

d$priceA_lag <- priceA_lag

> d
  Date       CountryA CountryB PriceA PriceB priceA_lag
1 2019-09-05       US    Japan     20     55         NA
2 2019-09-28    Japan  Germany     30     28         NA
3 2019-10-16   Canada       US     25     78         20
4 2019-10-28  Germany    Japan     60     17         30
```

Comment: Thanks, you almost nailed it! One minor issue: Your code scans the dates and unfortunately returns the row that is furthest apart (date-wise). E.g: d <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("01/08/2019","05/09/2019", "28/09/2019", "16/10/2019", "28/10/2019"),
  CountryA = c("Japan", "US", "Japan", "Canada", "Germany"),
  CountryB = c("US", "Japan", "Germany", "US", "Japan"),
  PriceA = c(70L, 20L, 30L, 25L, 60L),
  PriceB = c(10L, 55L, 28L, 78L, 17L)
) 
  .Here, in the last row for the price lag I want to get the price of 30 (from 28/09/2019), not of 70 (from 01/08/2019).

Comment: I caught the issue... The filtering function was using `date` instead of `Date`... Try it now...